# MACOS - No module named 'mmcv._ext'

Tags: python, macos, python-venv, pyenv

i am having trouble using the mmcv dependency.
Although it appears to be installed correctly, when I try to run my pytho script, I get the following error:

```
python .dev_scripts/check_installation.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Downloads/mmcv-2.x/.dev_scripts/check_installation.py", line 4, in <module>
    from mmcv.ops import box_iou_rotated
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/Progetti/project/Source/project/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mmcv/ops/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .active_rotated_filter import active_rotated_filter
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/Progetti/project/Source/project/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mmcv/ops/active_rotated_filter.py", line 10, in <module>
    ext_module = ext_loader.load_ext(
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/Progetti/project/Source/project/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mmcv/utils/ext_loader.py", line 13, in load_ext
    ext = importlib.import_module('mmcv.' + name)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.9.18/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mmcv._ext'
```

Encountering the problem on a macbook, I tried following this workaround: https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmdetection/issues/3765

But I still encounter the same problem.
does anyone have a workaround?
thanks in advance